# AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'plot'

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("ggplot")
import numpy as np
from mtspec import mtspec
from mtspec.util import _load_mtdata

data = np.loadtxt('262_V01_C00_R000_TEx_BL_4096H.dat')

spec,freq,jackknife,f_statistics,degrees_of_f = mtspec(data=data, delta= 4930.0, time_bandwidth=4 ,number_of_tapers=5, nfft= 4194304, statistics=True)


fig = plt.figure()      
ax2 = fig   
ax2.plot(freq, spec, color='black')
ax2.fill_between(freq, jackknife[:, 0], jackknife[:, 1],color="red", alpha=0.3)
ax2.set_xlim(freq[0], freq[-1])
ax2.set_ylim(0.1E1, 1E5)
ax2.set_xlabel("Frequency $")
ax2.set_ylabel("Power Spectral Density $)")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The problem is with the plotting part of my code.What should I change?I am using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You assign `ax2` to a `figure` object which doesn't have a `plot` method defined. You want to create your axes using `plt.axes` instead

```
ax2 = plt.axes()
# Instead of ax2 = fig
```

Answer (score 13):

instead of calling the figure with:

```
ax2 = fig #which just references the figure
```

try using `gca()` to extract the axes:

```
ax2 = fig.gca() #which is used to extract the axes
```

Comment: gca stands for "get current axis"