# Matplotlib returning a plot object

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a function that wraps `pyplot.plt` so I can quickly create graphs with oft-used defaults:

```
def plot_signal(time, signal, title='', xlab='', ylab='',
                line_width=1, alpha=1, color='k',
                subplots=False, show_grid=True, fig_size=(10, 5)):

    # Skipping a lot of other complexity here

    f, axarr = plt.subplots(figsize=fig_size)
    axarr.plot(time, signal, linewidth=line_width,
               alpha=alpha, color=color)
    axarr.set_xlim(min(time), max(time))
    axarr.set_xlabel(xlab)
    axarr.set_ylabel(ylab)
    axarr.grid(show_grid)

    plt.suptitle(title, size=16)
    plt.show()
```

However, there are times where I'd want to be able to return the plot so I can manually add/edit things for a specific graph. For example, I want to be able to change the axis labels, or add a second line to the plot after calling the function:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)

plot = plot_signal(np.arange(len(x)), x)

plot.plt(y, 'r')
plot.show()
```

I've seen a few questions on this ([How to return a matplotlib.figure.Figure object from Pandas plot function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936646/how-to-return-a-matplotlib-figure-figure-object-from-pandas-plot-function) and [AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'plot'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701137/attributeerror-figure-object-has-no-attribute-plot)) and as a result I've tried adding the following to the end of the function:

- `return axarr`
- `return axarr.get_figure()`
- `return plt.axes()`

However, they all return a similar error: `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'plt'`

Whats the correct way to return a plot object so it can be edited later?

Comment: Have you tried to return `fig = plt.gcf()`?

Comment: Everything is correct here except for calling to `plot.plt()` instead of `plot.plot()`. Silly mistake; can happen to everyone :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think the error is pretty self-explanatory. There is no such thing as `pyplot.plt`, or similar. `plt` is the quasi-standard abbreviated form of `pyplot` when being imported, i.e., `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Concerning the problem, the first approach, `return axarr` is the most versatile one. You get an axis, or an array of axes, and can plot to it.

The code may look like:

```
def plot_signal(x,y, ..., **kwargs):
    # Skipping a lot of other complexity here
    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=fig_size)
    ax.plot(x,y, ...)
    # further stuff
    return ax

ax = plot_signal(x,y, ...)
ax.plot(x2, y2, ...)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 32):

This is actually a great question that took me YEARS to figure out. A great way to do this is to pass a figure object to your code and have your function add an axis then return the updated figure. Here is an example:

```
fig_size = (10, 5)
f = plt.figure(figsize=fig_size)

def plot_signal(time, signal, title='', xlab='', ylab='',
                line_width=1, alpha=1, color='k',
                subplots=False, show_grid=True, fig=f):

    # Skipping a lot of other complexity here

    axarr = f.add_subplot(1,1,1) # here is where you add the subplot to f
    plt.plot(time, signal, linewidth=line_width,
               alpha=alpha, color=color)
    plt.set_xlim(min(time), max(time))
    plt.set_xlabel(xlab)
    plt.set_ylabel(ylab)
    plt.grid(show_grid)
    plt.title(title, size=16)
    
    return(f)
f = plot_signal(time, signal, fig=f)
f
```

Answer (score 9):

From the [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#the-object-oriented-interface-and-the-pyplot-interface), the recommended signature to use is:

```
def my_plotter(ax, data1, data2, param_dict):
    """
    A helper function to make a graph

    Parameters
    ----------
    ax : Axes
        The axes to draw to

    data1 : array
       The x data

    data2 : array
       The y data

    param_dict : dict
       Dictionary of keyword arguments to pass to ax.plot

    Returns
    -------
    out : list
        list of artists added
    """
    out = ax.plot(data1, data2, **param_dict)
    
    return out
```

This can be used as:

```
data1, data2, data3, data4 = np.random.randn(4, 100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
my_plotter(ax, data1, data2, {'marker': 'x'})
```

You should pass the axes rather than the figure. A `Figure` contains one or more `Axes`. `Axes` is an area where points can be specified in x-y format, 3d plot etc. Figure is something in which we graph the data - it can be jupyter notebook or the windows GUI etc.

Comment: What if your function produces a `Figure` consisting of multiple `Axes`? How do you handle this if you would like users to be able to modify that figure afterwards?