# Showing points coordinate in plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, coordinates

I want to show the (x,y) axis of points from a 2d array in a plot.

I know that by the following codes I can draw the points

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16], 'ro')
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
plt.show()
```

Which show me this picture:
[output of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtbJ0.jpg)

However, I want to show the x,y of each point near to them in the plot. Something like this
[Which I am looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqg2n.jpg)

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `plt.text()`? 
https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46028674/6361531

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,4,9,16]
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])

for i_x, i_y in zip(x, y):
    plt.text(i_x, i_y, '({}, {})'.format(i_x, i_y))

plt.show()
```