# How to annotate certain data points on a python scatterplot based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am almost done with my first real deal python data science project. However, there is one last thing I can't seem to figure out. I have the following code to create a plot for my PCA and K Means clustering algorithm:

```
y_axis = passers_pca_kmeans['Component 1']
x_axis = passers_pca_kmeans['Component 2']

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
sns.scatterplot(x_axis, y_axis, hue=passers_pca_kmeans['Segment'], palette=['g','r','c','m'])
plt.title('Clusters by PCA Components')
plt.grid(zorder=0,alpha=.4)

texts = [plt.text(x0,y0,name,ha='right',va='bottom') for x0,y0,name in zip(
    passers_pca_kmeans['Component 2'], passers_pca_kmeans['Component 1'], passers_pca_kmeans.name)]

adjust_text(texts)

plt.show
```

- I finally got the correct code to annotate the points using `adjustText`, but my plot has too many points to label them all; it looks like a mess with text everywhere.
- I would like to annotate the scatterplot based on the value in the column `'Segment'`.

  - The values in this column are the names of my four clusters `'first'`, `'second'`, `'third'`, `'fourth'`.
- How do I alter my `adjustText` code to only annotate points where `'Segment'='first'`?

  - Would this be an `np.where` situation?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14434334/1609514) shows how to add labels near data points individually. In the example they loop over all the points but you don't have to.

Comment: Oh wait, you're using Seaborn.  But it may still work I'm not sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding labels in x y scatter plot with seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027653/adding-labels-in-x-y-scatter-plot-with-seaborn)

Comment: That's where I'm at right now. However, labeling all data points is too much of a mess. I want to label certain data points based on a column value in my data frame.

Comment: The answers in the duplicate show using the entire dataframe, you just need to [Boolean select](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) the points you want and pass that instead of the entire dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could boolean slice your input into the `text` call, something like:

```
mask = (passers_kca_means["Subject"] == "first")
x = passers_kca_means["Component 2"][mask]
y = passers_kca_means["Component 1"][mask]
names = passers_kca_means.name[mask]

texts = [plt.text(x0,y0,name,ha='right',va='bottom') for x0,y0,name in zip(x,y,names)]
```

You could also make an unruly list comprehension by adding an `if` condition:

```
x = passers_kca_means["Component 2"]
y = passers_kca_means["Component 1"]
names = passers_kca_means.name
subjects = passers_kca_means["Subject"]

texts = [plt.text(x0,y0,name,ha='right',va='bottom') for x0,y0,name,subject in zip(x,y,names,subjects) if subject == "first"]
```

I bet there is an answer with `np.where` as well.

Comment: Awesome! This worked. Now, is there a possible way to extend the distance between the text and the points?

Comment: Does calling `adjust_text` not work here?  I'm not familiar with that module.

Comment: It does, I just need to figure out how to get a line that leads the text to its correct point now. I will check the documentation