# Seaborn Append column of labels for output within Graph

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, seaborn, cluster-analysis

I'm new to using Seaborn library.

I want to see each data point labelled with black text in the graph itself (beside data points), by manually appending a new column to `results`. How do I do this? How do I pass a 3rd column (labels) as a parameter?

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.scatterplot(x=results[:, 0], y=results[:, 1], alpha=1, s=100).plot()
fig = plt.gcf()
plt.scatter(x=results[:, 0], y=results[:, 1])
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

The data I am passing in `results`:

```
results = [[-0.01951522, 0.01933503]
 [-0.01793732, 0.01350751]
 [ 0.00615655, 0.00632767]
 [-0.0585989, -0.00142193]
 [-0.0348609 , 0.00997727]
 [ 0.10552081, -0.00200007]
 [ 0.1394851, -0.00433918]
 [-0.04782358, -0.01110567]
 [ 0.0211212, 0.01102468]
 [ 0.04887021, -0.00828152]
 [ 0.08460241, 0.00123756]
 [-0.02598796, -0.00897868]
 [-0.05668114, -0.00262177]
 [ 0.02583048, -0.01067982]
 [-0.10160218, -0.00816926]
 [-0.06857958, -0.00381181]]
```

This is what the output currently looks like:
[image: Seaborn Scatterplot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Seaborn package does not provide an API for annotation, but thankfully Seaborn is built on top of [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org) , which does.
To add annotation you can use the [.text(x, y, s)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html?highlight=text#matplotlib.pyplot.text) function, which specifies the x,y coordinates as `float` and text as `str`.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

results = np.array([[-0.01951522, 0.01933503], [-0.01793732, 0.01350751],[ 0.00615655, 0.00632767],[-0.0585989, -0.00142193],[-0.0348609 , 0.00997727],[ 0.10552081, -0.00200007],[ 0.1394851, -0.00433918],[-0.04782358, -0.01110567],[ 0.0211212, 0.01102468],[ 0.04887021, -0.00828152],[ 0.08460241, 0.00123756],[-0.02598796, -0.00897868],[-0.05668114, -0.00262177],[ 0.02583048, -0.01067982],[-0.10160218, -0.00816926],[-0.06857958, -0.00381181]])

ax = sns.scatterplot(x= results[:, 0], y=results[:, 1], alpha=1, s=100)
s = [str(x) for x in range(1, len(results))]
for point in range(0, len(results)-1):
    ax.text(x=results[point, 0]+0.003, y=results[point, 1]-0.0012, s=s[point])
```

[scatter plot with annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQcdr.png)

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027653/adding-labels-in-x-y-scatter-plot-with-seaborn) question. You might want to google your question first next time.

Comment: I did see this. However, this isn't what I have asked but does yield the same outcome.

Comment: Reading your question, I assumed you wanted to add labels to your plot. After reading it a second time and your comment, I understand you want to pass an additional argument so that labels will appear magically. This is obviously not how it works. You can read the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) of the `seaborn.scatterplot` function. Also, if it were that simple, wouldn't you expect that to be the top answer to the other question?