# Label specific points in seaborn based on x-values

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, seaborn

I have a dataframe where idividuals have some scores. The idea is to highlight the reference indididual (check) in red and the individuals with a lower score in green. Following similar problem on StackOverflow ([Adding labels in x y scatter plot with seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027653/adding-labels-in-x-y-scatter-plot-with-seaborn)), I was able to highlight the check in red. However, I failed to highlight in green the two individuals (id_11, id_17) with a lower score. I got the error
"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
Please, find below my code. Thank you in advance for your help.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Individual Name': ['id_1', 'check', 'id_3', 'id_4', 'id_5', 'id_6', 'id_7', 'id_8', 'id_9', 'id_10', 'id_11', 'id_12', 'id_13', 'id_14', 'id_15', 'id_16', 'id_17', 'id_18', 'id_19', 'id_20', 'id_21', 'id_22', 'id_23', 'id_24', 'id_25', 'id_26', 'id_27', 'id_28', 'id_29', 'id_30'],
     'feature': [0.508723818, 0.438733637, 0.718100026, 0.506722786, 0.520924985, 0.69302915, 0.659499198, 0.547989555, 0.714309067, 0.617602669, 0.35364303, 0.534064345, 0.59011931, 0.488031738, 0.511025466, 0.655582175, 0.32029745, 0.594929278, 0.562511802, 0.571763799, 0.681324482, 0.40444921, 0.628999099, 0.497668065, 0.690914914, 0.530561335, 0.798924312, 0.671025127, 0.71243462, 0.539980784],
     'score': [91.5, 89.75, 94.25, 91.75, 91.75, 93.5, 93.25, 92.25, 94.0, 93.0, 89.25, 92.0, 92.5, 91.5, 91.5, 93.5, 88.5, 92.25, 92.0, 93.25, 93.25, 90.25, 92.75, 90.75, 94.0, 92.0, 95.75, 93.75, 94.5, 92.0]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='score', y='feature')
plt.text(x=df['score'][df['Individual Name'] == 'check'], y=df['feature'][df['Individual Name'] == 'check'], s='check', color='red')
score_of_check = df['score'][
    df['Individual Name'] == 'check']  # reference value for highlighting idividuals that have a lower score
print(score_of_check)
# label points if score is lower than score_of_check
for x in df['score']:
    if x < score_of_check:
        print(x)  # Even print generate the error
        plt.text(x=df['score'], y=df['feature'], s=df['Individual Name'],
                 color='green')  # Ultimately I would like to label the 2 materials, id_11 and id_17 in green

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Comment: The problem here is that `score_of_check` isn't a single value, it is a `Series` which happens to have 1 element, but could have more.  You could try `score_of_check = score_of_check.values[0]` to convert it to a single value that can be used in an `if`-test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to JohanC's comment, here is some code that makes it work. The key is to set up an index based off of the size (rows) of your dataframe. The `if` was not comparing compatible data types - note the variable `score_of_check` is a series and needs to be converted to a value for comparison. You also need to use your index to supply single element coordinates and labels to the `plt.text` function, otherwise you are trying to assign the entire column each time you run it.

```
for ind in range(len(df)):
   #print(ind)
   if df['score'][ind] < score_of_check.values[0]:
       print(ind)  # Even print generate the error
       plt.text(x=df['score'][ind], y=df['feature'][ind], s=df['Individual Name'][ind],
             color='green')  # Ultimately I would like to label the 2 materials, id_11 and id_17 in green
```