# matplotlib: How to return a matplotlib object then plot as subplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I checked this SO [Matplotlib returning a plot object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925337/matplotlib-returning-a-plot-object) but it does not really fit to my question.

What I would like to do is:

```
def func1():
   fig1 =  plt.plot (np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1))
   return fig1

def func2()
   return plt.plot (np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.02))


fig1 = func1()
fig2 = func2()
plt.figure()
plt.add_subplot(fig1)
plt.add_subplot(fig2)
plt.show()
```

The above code is just a main idea. Could you suggest me how to do?

Thanks

Comment: rather than returning something like `fig` object you might consider passing `Axis` to your plotting functions instead.

Answer (score 13):

The idea would be to let your functions plot to an axes. Either you provide this axes as argument to the function or you let it take the current axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def func1(ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    line, = ax.plot (np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1))
    return line

def func2(ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    line, = ax.plot (np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.02))
    return line


fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
func1(ax1)
func2(ax2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: So the other way around is impossible?

Comment: @MasterScrat No, very little is impossible. But matplotlib is not designed to have artists copied between figures. So any other solution becomes utterly complicated (and is unsupported). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46906599/4124317) for the principle - which might already not work anymore by now.